# How to count number of checkboxes in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to `count` the number of `checkboxes` that have been checked in a dynamic table that changes `size`, depending on a database file.

For testing purposes, every time a `checkbox` is `checked`, it will alert whether the `counter` incremented, or conversely, if a `checkbox` is `unchecked`, the `counter` decrements.

The problem is that the `checkboxes` increments/decrements depending on the `checkbox` of the very first `row`. For example if the first `checkbox` in the first `row` is `checked` and you check 3 additional `checkboxes` from `3` different `rows`, it will increment and `alert` `"4"`.

If the checkbox in the first row is `unchecked`, but you check `3` other `checkboxes` in `3` different `rows`, it will alert "-3". How would you edit the code so that it correctly `counts` the number of `checked` `checkboxes`?

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Check</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>UPC</th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in data %}
    <tr>
        <td><label><input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onchange="countChecks()"></label></td>
        <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[3]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<script>
    counter = 0;

    function countChecks() {
        if (document.getElementById('myCheck').checked == true) {
            counter += 1;
            alert(counter);
        }
        if (document.getElementById('myCheck').checked == false) {
            counter -= 1;
            alert(counter);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can just do:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
```

This will give you the number of checked checkboxes.

Comment: You can check 'Why' it didn't worked before in the next answer!
And if @Maria solved your problem, mark her answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `document.getElementById('myCheck')` only returns you the first node, that's why it returns -3 to you, it counts '-1' three times. You can check thisway: `document.getElementById('myCheck').lenght` (this will return 1 as it only select the first coincidence to the ID).

You can solve it this way: add a class to the checkboxes and in the `countChecks` function you select the items by class `document.getElementsByClassName("example");` and iterate them to count.

Comment: Thank you, this explanation with all the others really help me understand why my logic was off and expanded tools I can use

Comment: @Yuan-XunLee No problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is you seem to be generated multiple DOM elements with the same `id`. Instead, consider using `classes`. Then, you can use a query selector to get all in that class that are checked and output the number of items that match.

```js
function countChecks() {
  const checked = document.querySelectorAll('.myCheck:checked');
  console.log(checked.length);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" onchange="countChecks()"></label></td>
    <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" onchange="countChecks()"></label></td>
    <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" onchange="countChecks()"></label></td>
    <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much for explaining, I understand why my logic didn't make sense now.